# Why all the write executions are blocked when acquiring a write lock in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Why all the write executions are blocked when acquiring a write lock in mysql?

when a session is acquiring a write lock (have not acquired the lock), all the write executions are blocked. I think this is illogical.

Session does not acquire the lock means the lock does not work.

If I want a unblocking before acquired lock, how to do?

For example:

Session A:

```
begin;
select * from test;
```

Session B:

```
lock table test write; # the session is blocked.
```

Session C:

```
insert into test values (xxx); # the session is blocked.
```

**Both session b and session c are "wait for metadata lock".**

I think session c can insert successful as the session b **DOES NOT** acquire the lock **YET**. But all the write executions are put into a queue named "wait for metadata lock" and are blocked.

I want a lock which does not block other queries when being not acquired yet.

My case is online ddl:

The scripts:

```
lock table test write; # will block all queries if long transations exists;
remember some markers;
unlock tables;
create tmp_table;    
add some triggers; # will block all the queries if long transations exists;
copy data;
rename table names; will block all the queries if long transations exists;
```

It's too dangerous if there are long transation.

Comment: I for one have no idea what you are talking about. Can you show us the sequence of SQL statements you use? e.g. details on how do you "acquire the write lock"?

Comment: i made some modifications.

Comment: Session B **acquires** the lock when it executes `lock table`. Not "sometime" later. The whole process seems a bit strange to me. Why do you have a session locking a table if you *know* there are other sessions trying to insert into that table? Sounds like using proper transactions would solve your problem without table locks (which are a sure method to make your application non-scalable)

Comment: What do you mean 'not being acquired yet'? LOCK TABLE means lock the table, *now,* and that must block both reads and writes, by definition. If you don't want it locked, don't lock it.

Comment: Both session b and session c are "wait for metadata lock". The session is blocked. The statement "LOCK TABLE" does not execute successful as it need something and is blocked.

Comment: They are both blocked waiting for the potentially enormous SELECT * in session A to finish, unless there is a other session you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Why doesn't session B lock the table yet? You tell it to lock the table, right? So why wouldn't it? The whole essence of getting a lock like that is to prevent other sessions from writing in the mean time. If you don't want that, don't get a lock.

Comment: session A has an unfinished transcation which blocked the session B's lock table statement.